# search array value by index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

i have two documents stored in `elasticsearch` database

one is

```
{
   q :["python" , "foo"]
}
```

and other is

```
{
   q :["python" , "moo","foo"]
}
```

now my problem is to `search` document in which `python` is on index `0` and `foo` is on index `1` how to acheive this?
i have read about `bool` query of `elasticsearch` but could not figure out how to use it kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "_source.q[0] == \"python\" && _source.q[1] == \"foo\" "
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although `document fields` are suggested since they are loaded into memory and are fast to access but they are **not ordered**. Refer [this](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Accessing-array-field-within-Native-Plugin-td4042848.html) and hence in this case we need to use `_source`

Comment: Also you need to make sure that [scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) for this to work.